# When someone is insisting you do something which you dislike

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Please imagine someone is insisting you do something (e.g., going somewhere or trying something, etc.) that you dislike for certain reasons. For instance, at the place they want you to go, there is someone you don't like or what they tend  to have there smells bad to you, and so on.

What structure is used normally in English to indicate the message below?

> (Go /eat, etc.) just as a test this time and afterwards if you feel it’s bad, don’t (go/eat) anymore.

This is an exact translation from what we say in our language. I'm sure it makes good sense to you, but what about its possible grammatical and structural problems?

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether the disliking is a fact or an expectation. If it's a fact, I don't think we need to see how it goes, and I might say something like, *Okay, I'll go. Just this once.* Your original phrase seems to be more like an expectation, though.

Comment: "Sure, I'll [*give it a shot*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+it+a+shot), and if it is really bad I won't go again." Not necessarily negative, but it can be understood that way. It is more of a "I'll try it once and see what happens".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual phrasing will primarily depend on the context, of course, so there can be no generic example that encompasses all possible usages. Here are a couple of examples that came to my mind though:

Example #1:

> Look, go and see what he has to say. You've got absolutely nothing to lose. If you don't like his ideas, then forget about him.

Example #2:

> Just go and try. It's not gonna do you any harm. If you don't like it, just don't go there anymore.

Comment: I think you get the OP's request right (and I thought it was about the reply to such insistence). To add a couple short phrases along the same lines as your answer, I'd like to suggest: *Give it a try. Give him a chance*

Comment: How about these choices? **1)** **"Give it a (chance / try); if you didn't like this idea, just don't eat it anymore"**  OR **2) "Go there just this once; if you didn't like this idea, just don't eat it anymore"**  OR **3) "Give it a chance / try; if you didn't like it, just don't eat it anymore"** OR **4) "Do it just this once; if you didn't like it, just don't eat it anymore."**@Cookie Monster

Comment: @DamkerngT. I would be thankful if you could give your opinion too on my above question. :)

Comment: They're okayish, I think. Just be careful with the tense. I'd say *if you don't like ...* would be more normal.